# Suppose $g: R \to R$ is a continuous function such that $g(0) = 0$, and suppose $f : R\to R$ is such that$|f(x) - f(y)|\leq g( x - y) $ ...

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose $g: R \to R$ is a continuous function such that $g(0) = 0$, and suppose $f : R\to R$ is such that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq g( x - y) $ for all $x$ and $y$. Show that $f$ is continuous.

I really need help...

this is what I got

$|x - 0  | < \delta / 2 \Rightarrow | g(x) - g(0) | = | g(x) |  < \epsilon /2 $

Similarly $\mid y -0 \mid $...

and then $ \mid x - y \mid  = \mid x - 0 + 0 - y \mid = \mid x - 0 \mid + \mid y - 0 \mid < \delta$

and then $|g(x-y) - g(0) | = | g(x-y) - 0 | = | g(x) - g( y) | = | g(x) - g(0) + g(0) -g(y) |  \leq | g(x) - g(0) | + | g(x) - g(y) | < \epsilon$

= > $|g(x-y) | < \epsilon$

so I can say that $\mid f(x) - f(y) \mid < \epsilon$

Is this right?

Comment: I suppose $g$ is nonnegative? Otherwise it wouldn't really make much sense.

Comment: I don't think so.. problem doesn't mention about that.

Comment: since absolute value is nonnegative, it is implicitly imply that $g$ is indeed nonnegative.

Comment: Some MathJax tips: `|` gives the correct spacing for absolute value, $\mid$ should be used for divisibility. You can use $\to$ `$\to$`, $\Rightarrow$ `$\Rightarrow$`, $\implies$ `$\implies$`.

Answer (score 1):

Use continuity of g at zero to get uniform continuity of f.

Comment: can I do $\mid x - 0  \mid < \delta / 2 => \mid g(x) - g(0) \mid = \mid g(x) \mid  < \epsilon /2 $

simlarly $\mid y -0 \mid $... 

and then $ \mid x - y \mid  = \mid x - 0 + 0 - y \mid = \mid x - 0 \mid + \mid y - 0 \mid < \delta$

Comment: and then $\mid g(x-y) - g(0) \mid = \mid g(x-y) - 0 \mid = \mid g(x) - g( y) \mid = \mid g(x) - g(0) + g(0) -g(y) \mid  \leq \mid g(x) - g(0) \mid + \mid g(x) - g(y) \mid < \epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

The content of the givens is the following: If $x$ is near $y$ then $|x-y|$ is small. Therefore $x-y$ is near zero, and so is $g(x-y)$. It follows that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq g(x-y)$ is small as well. Now we have to build a logic $\epsilon$-$\delta$-chain establishing the continuity of $f$ according to the definition.

Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. Since $g(0)=0$, and $g$ is continuous at $0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|g(t)|<\epsilon$ as soon as $|t|<\delta$.
We now go back to $f$: Assume that $x$, $y\in{\mathbb R}$ are so near to each other that $|x-y|<\delta$. Then $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq g(x-y)<\epsilon\ .$$
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary we have therewith proven that $f$ is actually *uniformly continuous* on ${\mathbb R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n = x$,

$$|f(x_n)-f(x)| \leq g(x_n-x)$$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |f(x_n)-f(x)| \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g(x_n-x)=g(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n-x)=g(0)=0$$

Hence

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |f(x_n)-f(x)|=0$$

Hence as $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n=x \implies \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)=f(x)$

Edit:

I just see your attempt, I don't think you can justify that $$|g(x-y)|=|g(x)-g(y)|$$

Comment: I realized that domain is all real numbers, so x +y  is also in R 
we know that g is continuous which means that 
$\mid x - 0 \mid < \delta = > \mid f(x) -f(0) =  \epsilon $ instead of x, if I put x - y since domain is all real numbers... 
$\mid x- y - 0 \mid < \delta = > \mid f(x- y) - f(0)\mid < \epsilon $

Comment: I think you meant to describe $g$ rather than $f$ in your comment? $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0, |x-y|< \delta \implies  |g(x-y)-g(0)| < \epsilon$. Good job. Hence $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0, |x-y|< \delta \implies  |f(x)-f(y)| \leq |g(x-y)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: oh yeah I wanted to describe g not f

Comment: but If I do that... what if c is not 0 .... ?

Comment: I feel like what I am done can only be satisfied when c = 0 .... ,so I am not sure whether I have to consider when c is not 0 ....

Comment: I don't understand your notation, what do you mean by $c$?